# jms Mule max redelivery exceeded

Tags: jms, mule, hornetq

I have very simple setup of MULE reading from the HornetQ queue and saving Object to database:

setup below:

```
<jms:connector name="connector.jms" maxRedelivery="1" connectionFactory-ref="hornetQConnectionFactory" doc:name="JMS"
        createMultipleTransactedReceivers="true"
        numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="100"
        acknowledgementMode="AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE">
    <reconnect count="50" frequency="5000"/>       
</jms:connector>
<flow name="jmsListenerFlow1" doc:name="jmsListenerFlow1">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="adsLogQueue" connector-ref="connector.jms" doc:name="JMS">
        <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    <component >
        <spring-object bean="logSaver"/>
    </component>

</flow>
```

Why do I get a message that message has been redelivered 9 times on endpoint while maxRedelivery setting is 1 ? What does it exactly mean ?

hornetQConnectionFactory:

```
        <bean name="hornetQTransportConfiguration" class="org.hornetq.api.core.TransportConfiguration">
        <constructor-arg value="org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="host" value="${jms.host}" /> 
                <entry key="port" value="${jms.port}" /> 
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>

    </bean>
    <bean name="hornetQConnectionFactory" class="org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="false"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="hornetQTransportConfiguration"/>
        <property name="minLargeMessageSize" value="250000"/>
        <property name="cacheLargeMessagesClient" value="false"/>
    </bean>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Stack trace below.

```
ERROR 2012-10-19 01:04:07,283 [Thread-3013 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1442093417)]: 

Message               : "Message with id "ID:e6a0b303-1977-11e2-96d4-810571a3fe10" has been redelivered 9 times on endpoint "jms://adsLogQueue", which exceeds the maxRedelivery setting of 1 on the connector "connector.jms". Message payload is of type: HornetQObjectMessage
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2

Exception stack is:
1. "Message with id "ID:e6a0b303-1977-11e2-96d4-810571a3fe10" has been redelivered 9 times on endpoint "jms://adsLogQueue", which exceeds the maxRedelivery setting of 1 on the connector "connector.jms". Message payload is of type: HornetQObjectMessage (org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.MessageRedeliveredException)
  org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.JmsXRedeliveryHandler:91 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/transport/jms/redelivery/MessageRedeliveredException.html)

Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.MessageRedeliveredException: "Message with id "ID:e6a0b303-1977-11e2-96d4-810571a3fe10" has been redelivered 9 times on endpoint "jms://adsLogQueue", which exceeds the maxRedelivery setting of 1 on the connector "connector.jms". Message payload is of type: HornetQObjectMessage
    at org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.JmsXRedeliveryHandler.handleRedelivery(JmsXRedeliveryHandler.java:91)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.MultiConsumerJmsMessageReceiver$JmsWorker.preProcessMessage(MultiConsumerJmsMessageReceiver.java:418)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractReceiverWorker$1$1.process(AbstractReceiverWorker.java:120)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Could you share the hornetQConnectionFactory configuration as well?

Comment: @genjosanzo Added Thanks for looking into this

Comment: Do you have several Mule instances connected to the same queue?

Comment: @DavidDossot Hi yes i have two mule instances connected to the same queue on Production, although It happened also on my local environment where there is only one mule connected to the queue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing to note is that Mule is using `JmsXRedeliveryHandler`, which means it has detected that HornetQ supports the `JMS_X_DELIVERY_COUNT` header and will take care of counting the re-deliveries. In that situation, Mule fully relies on HornetQ for providing an accurate count of re-deliveries.

The fact this exception is thrown means that a JMS message has been presented to Mule with a redelivery count that exceeds the count configured on the JMS connector (1 in your case).

Since you consume in a transaction, what's likely to happen is that HornetQ will rollback and represent this message to Mule, on each restart, again and again unless you've configured a maximum redelivery count on HornetQ itself.

My advice is: set the same redelivery count on Mule and HornetQ or use -1 on Mule (no limit) and fully rely on HornetQ's redelivery limit.